# Why do some developers define font-size twice with different units?

Tags: html, css

I develop website themes using starter themes and I see the developers defining properties twice with different units, for example :

```
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #404040;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Because of this - http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you have provided, the first `font-size` defined (`16px`) will provide a fallback for browsers that *do not* support `rem` units. Browsers that *do* support `rem` units will use the latter `font-size` (`1rem`) because it is defined after the first and therefore supersedes it.

```
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #404040;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;             /*This is set first and provides a fallback if rem units are not supported */
    font-size: 1rem;             /*This second defintion supersedes the first in supported browsers because it is defined after the first definition */
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Here's CANIUSE which details browser support etc. It's actually really good, support-wise; it's only really IE8 or lower that it will fail in: http://caniuse.com/rem

Here's a good article covering REM units:
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/